# MySQL Transactions and Interference from other queries

Tags: mysql

Suppose I want to create a row if it does not exist OR increment a count if it does. And I do it in separate queries in a transaction (possibly with other queries and application logic)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
...
SELECT COUNT(id) AS rows FROM tbl;
...
# if rows > 0
INSERT INTO tbl ...
# else
UPDATE tbl ...
...
COMMIT
```

Its possible for multiple rows to be inserted into the DB because of interference correct? What if I use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` can I be sure the condition holds?

Comment: For the first scenario (procedure + transaction) - yes, you can get duplicates. The duplicates are *always* prevented by a `UNIQUE` key and never by your own checks. Using transaction isolates the data for that transaction only. That means that two transactions operate on their data snapshot (unless specified otherwise). Each can see that there's no such record and each will insert the record - therefore, producing duplicates. `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is what you're after, you will be sure that no such record exists and you can increment the counter if it does.